# How to reduce number of parameters in MATLAB anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

How is it possible to reduce the number of parameters in an anonymous function in MATLAB?
Here is an short example:

```
f = @(p,x) p(1).*x.^2 + p(2);
p = [1,2];
g = @(x) f(p,x);
```

So long this works fine. But I would like to export the final function with all parameters to a string.

```
string = func2str(g);
```

The result is `@(x) f(p,x)` but in my mind it should be something like `@(x) 1.*x.^2 + 2`.

How is it possible to realize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the symbolic math toolbox to simplify:

```
function h = cleanhandle(f)
    syms x;
    h = matlabFunction(f(x));
end
```

Usage:

```
>> g2 = cleanhandle(g)
g2 = 
    @(x)x.^2+2.0
```

---

Here a version for functions with more than one input argument:

```
function f=cleanhandle(f)
    n=nargin(f);
    A=sym('A', [n 1]);
    A=mat2cell(A,ones(n,1));
    f=matlabFunction(f(A{:}));
end
```